# Cache Directory Issue in Tinymce Editor

Tags: php, caching, file-permissions

In my Php site i configure Tinymce Editor. In this editor there is a directory named "cache". Whenever i apply 777 permission on cache directory the images display work in popup, but whenever i change permission to 755 dipslay of images is not working. I check in the cache directory there is a file "timthumb_cacheLastCleanTime.touch". My question is why image display is not working on 755 and what is the function of this "timthumb_cacheLastCleanTime.touch" file in cache directory? I search about it but failed to find any useful information.

Comment: Who are the owner and group of the file? Does the user that the web server is running under either own the file or belong to the group?

Comment: i want to know the functionality of "timthumb_cacheLastCleanTime.touch" this file. what .touch extension tell about that which type of file this is?

Comment: I have no idea. I can try to help you with your permission issue though if you provide me with the answer to my last question